# How to convert STM32 snippet (code examples) written for target device STM32F072B to STM32F030r8

Tags: arm, stm32, keil, nucleo, stm32f0

Dears,

I am newbie in embedded systems.

I have downloaded code examples from [st.com](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f072bdiscovery.html#tools-software) written for target device STM32F072B. As I am using Nucleo-64 with STM32F030r8 MCU, I need to convert the downloaded code examples to support my target device STM32F030r8.

I can build the code examples (written for STM32F072B) in Keil, but when I am changing the target device to STM32F030r8 I am getting an error:

```
..\system_stm32f0xx.c(301): error:  #20: identifier "RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC_HSI48_PREDIV" is undefined
```

Please help me either by telling the way to convert the downloaded code examples to support my target device STM32F030r8.

Regards
Niyas

Comment: What example is it ? Usually code examples are published for all (or most) STM32s. Are you sure there isn't an example already ported to your target ?

Comment: Its not for a specific example. Its happening for the entire code example package(code examples). Directly I can build the project and errors, But I am getting error when I am changing the target device. Or else please suggest the way to convert the code examples written for a specific target to another target device

Comment: Your question is not clear. please edit and clarify it. It you are using a code example from STMicro as it is, it should compile on Keil easily. Read the documentation from STMicro, the "getting started" for STM32CubeF0 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank-you Dears,
**I found the answer. Guillaume Petitjean 's reply made me to read more documents and finally I made it.**

Question:
The STM32SnippetsF0 (C-code examples) downloaded from https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32snippetsf0.html#overview is designed to run on the STM32F072B Discovery board. So changing target device(my case STM32F030r8) need many changes like adding supported header files etc. 
*I got the mentioned error previously because I compiled simply after changing target device in setting but without adding proper header file. :(

*I was asking this. Don't know whether I asked properly. Anyway the solution i found is sharing with you all.

Answer:

> This document tells how the snippet code can be used on other target device

https://www.st.com/resource/en/data_brief/stm32snippetsf0.pdf

After reading the document and adding necessary driver header files I am able to compile and build the code

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the exciting world of embedded systems where peripherals even change within sub-families of devices.

The missing macro your compiler complains about is actually a pretty good hint on whats wrong. Looking at the [STM32F072B reference manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/c2/f8/8a/f2/18/e6/43/96/DM00031936.pdf/files/DM00031936.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031936.pdf) ST lists the following available clock sources:

> Various clock sources can be used to drive the system clock
>    (SYSCLK):
>
> - HSI 8 MHz RC oscillator clock
> - HSE oscillator clock
> - PLL clock
> - HSI48 48 MHz RC oscillator clock (available on STM32F04x, STM32F07x and STM32F09x devices only)

Comparing that to the [STM32F030 reference manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/cf/10/a8/c4/29/fb/4c/42/DM00091010.pdf/files/DM00091010.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00091010.pdf) we can see that the HSI48 clock is clearly missing on this device.

> Various clock sources can be used to drive the system clock
>    (SYSCLK):
>
> - HSI 8 MHz RC oscillator clock
> - HSE oscillator clock
> - PLL clock

I guess that some part of the code snippet you downloaded tries to use that missing HSI48 clock somehow. Switching the device inside the IDE most likely caused your project to use another device header where the macro "RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC_HSI48_PREDIV" simply isn't defined. You might be able to use another clock source instead, but your question doesn't contain enough information to answer that for certain.

Generally when working with embedded devices you have to be very careful when switching from one microcontroller to another. Even the tiniest differences (even a single register or a single bit) can break your build or even worse your hardware.